# On the Hessian of a smooth $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ at a critical point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am asked to prove the following from Tapp's *Differential Geometry*:

> Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open and let $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth. Let $\lbrace u,v \rbrace$ denote the local coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$; i.e. let $f=f(u,v)$. Assume that $q\in U$ is a critical point of $f$, such that $df_q(w)=0$ for all $w\in\mathbb{R}^2$; equivalently, $f_u(q)=f_v(q)=0$. Let $\gamma:I\to U$ be a regular curve with $\gamma(0)=q$ and $\gamma'(0)=w:=(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.
>
> Show that $\mathrm{Hess}(f)_q(w)=(f\circ\gamma)''(0)=a^2 f_{uu}(q)+2ab f_{uv}(q)+b^2 f_{vv}(q)$.

I know how to compute the Hessian matrix for maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, but am a bit confused by differentials of general maps.

I tried
\begin{align}
(f\circ\gamma)''(0)=&
\left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} \frac{d}{dt} (f\circ\gamma)'(t) \\
=& \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} \left( df_{\gamma(t)} \circ \gamma' \right)(t) \\
=&
\left. \left( d \left( df_{\gamma(t)} \right)_{\gamma'(t)} \circ \gamma'' \right)(t) \right\rvert_{t=t_0} \\
=& d\left( df_q \right)_w (\gamma''(0))
\end{align}
but that's about as far as I got.

---

Edit: (*why*) is it true that $\mathrm{Hess}(f)_q(w)=w^{\top} \mathbf{H}f(q) w =
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{H}f(q) \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}?
$

Comment: What you write after "I tried" is excellent. Use the Leibniz rule to differentiate the expression on the right hand side. Since $q$ is a critical point, one term vanishes.

Comment: I don't know how the Leibniz rule applies, unless you mean "chain rule" as opposed to "product rule." I should have added that I did try to evaluate the latter expression but only got $\left. \left( d \left( df_{\gamma(t)} \right)_{\gamma'(t)} \circ \gamma'' \right)(t) \right\rvert_{t=0}$, and I didn't know how to evaluate further. I'll edit to reflect this. I'm also slightly confused over the fact that we can only compose (not multiply) functions since $\gamma$ is a vector function.

Comment: I should also say that I'm not sure what to do with $d\left( df_q \right)_w$, though my intuition tells me it should be equal to $\mathrm{Hess}(f)_q(w)$

Comment: I've tried following the proofs of the product and chain rules but to no avail. Any clarification in the form of an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your calculation is incorrect. I suggest doing the calculation using coordinates $x^1, \dots, x^n$ with $n = 1$ and $n=2$. When you are learning things like this, it is easy to make mistakes using abstract notation like this. Do it first using coordinates.

Comment: @Deane I followed your suggestion and got the desired result, but what exactly was incorrect in my question? I thought I applied the chain rule for differentials appropriately, even though the second differential is only well-defined at critical points.

Comment: @terrygarcia, you should be able to compare line by line the two different calculations you made and see where things go wrong. Specifically, the third line appears wrong to me. There should be more the one term, each corresponding to a slot where $t$ appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work in local coordinates, as Deane said in the comments. I'll preface this by noting that I prefer to express my derivatives in a coordinate-free manner wherever possible, even when using local coordinates. That is, I prefer notation like $\partial_{1,1} f \vert_{\gamma(t)}$, $f^{(2,0)}$ and $Dg$ as opposed to ${\partial^2 f} / {\partial u^2}$ and ${dg}/{dt}$, because the (partial) derivative does not "care" about (informally speaking) and is unchanged by local coordinates. In what follows, the symbol $\partial_{i,j}$ reads as "differentiate with respect to the $i$-th argument, followed by the $j$-th argument."

Now, let's set $\gamma(t)=(u(t),v(t))$ and look at
\begin{align}
(f \circ \gamma)'(t)=& \partial_1 f\vert_{\gamma(t)} u'(t) + \partial_2 f\vert_{\gamma(t)} v'(t) \,,
\end{align}

We then differentiate a second time, carefully applying the chain and product rules.

\begin{align}
(f \circ \gamma)''(t)=& \partial_1 f\vert_{\gamma(t)} u''(t) + \partial_{1,1} f\vert_{\gamma(t)} u'(t)^2 \\
+& 2 u'(t) v'(t) \partial_{1,2} f\vert_{\gamma(t)} \\
+& \partial_{2,2} f\vert_{\gamma(t)} v'(t)^2 + \partial_2 f\vert_{\gamma(t)} v''(t)
\end{align}

So then
\begin{align}
(f \circ \gamma)''(0) =& \partial_1 f\vert_{q} u''(t) + \partial_{1,1} f\vert_{q} a^2 \\
+& 2ab \,\partial_{1,2} f\vert_{q} \\
+& \partial_{2,2} f\vert_{q} b^2 + \partial_2 f\vert_{q} v''(t) \,,
\end{align}
but since $q$ is a critical point of $f$, we know that the first-order partial derivatives vanish at $q$, so the above becomes

$$(f \circ \gamma)''(0) = \partial_{1,1} f\vert_{q} a^2
+ 2ab \,\partial_{1,2} f\vert_{q}
+ \partial_{2,2} f\vert_{q} b^2 := \mathrm{Hess}(f)_q (w) \,,$$
or, in a more familiar form

$$\mathrm{Hess}(f)_q(w)=(f \circ \gamma)''(0) = a^2 f_{uu}(q) + 2ab f_{uv}(q) + b^2 f_{vv}(q) \,.$$